# How to differentiate self signed and CA's signed certificate using java code?

Tags: java, security, keystore

How to differentiate self-signed and CA's signed certificate using java code?

Comment: Root CA certificates are self-signed too, so what is it *really* you need to know?

Comment: I generated a certificate and signed on it and I imported it. CA's certificates from e-token and my self-signed certificates are loaded into Keystore using java code. I need to differentiate between my self signed certificate and CA's certificates in my java code.

Comment: I need to load only trusted CA's certificates but not my self signed certificate.